# How to change background color regarding position of the cursor

Tags: background, position, cursor

I have the following problem: How to write javascript code, when I move the cursor on the first third of the display, to change the background color. When it's the second or third part of the display, to change the background color.
 I need three different colors regarding the position of the cursor.

Comment: Do you want to use plain JavaScript, or do you have a framework loaded? What parts of the question are you having problems with? Detecting cursor position? Determining cursor position relative to window position? Changing the background color?

Comment: var body = document.body;
     body.onmousemove = function(e) {
      var x = e.pageX;
      var y = e.pageY;
        
     }
     I don't know how to link cursor with changing of background, and how to determine position of the cursor.

Comment: Anyone ? Thank you.

Comment: When you say first third of the display is that horizontal or vertical? Please [edit] the question to update it with clarifying information.